# "Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '&#x;', to be a valid callback" ; PHP Error

Tags: php, html, json, function

Setting up an App that should put Ads over images and I'm getting this WordPress error when running the code and it's been a frustrating week trying to fix this thing.

```
function cwali_json_encode_utf8callback($matches){
    return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}
function cwali_json_encode_utf8($json)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', cwali_json_encode_utf8callback($matches), json_encode($json));
}
```

I expect it to work but it gives me the following error : Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '&#x;', to be a valid callback.

If someone could please come up with a solution, that would be amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: You need to pass the function name, not call the function right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your call

```
preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', cwali_json_encode_utf8callback($matches), json_encode($json));
```

instead of passing the callback function, you call the function, so its return value is passed as the argument. Try

```
preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', 'cwali_json_encode_utf8callback', json_encode($json));
```